# Use the same Random Generated Number Several Times

Tags: python, random, input, python-3.4

I'm writing a code where the user inputs a sentence, inputting one word at a time. When they type 'exit', the code returns "Your original sentence was sentence. Word number (generate random number) is (the word that corresponds to that number)".

For example, the sentence is "This is a cool code", it'll return "Your original sentence was This is a cool code. Word number 3 is a.

Right now, my code gets two different random numbers and words so it'll be like "Word number 2 is this" or something. How should I fix this and get it to work properly?

```
print ('Think of a sentence')
print ('Type the sentence one word at a time pressing enter after each word')
print ("When you have finished the sentence enter 'exit'")
print ('')
sentence = []
while True:
    word = input('')
    print ('Accepted', word)
    if word == 'exit':
                print ('')
                print ('Your original sentence was')
                outputString = " ".join(sentence)
                print (outputString)
                wordCount = len(outputString.split())
                pleaseWork =  (random.randint(0,wordCount))
                print('Word number ',pleaseWork,' is ', (sentence[pleaseWork]))

                break
    sentence.append(word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there!

When you do:

```
pleaseWork =  (random.randint(0,wordCount))
```

You're getting a number (in the `pleaseWork` variable) between zero and `len(outputString)`, which (since `outputString` is a string) will give you the number of characters in `outputString`.

Try it out:

```
>>> len("Hello, my name is BorrajaX")
26
```

However, what you really want, is a random index between `0` and the number of items in your `sentence` list, right? Because when you do this: `sentence[pleaseWork]` you're using `pleaseWork` as an index for the `sentence` list, not for your `outputString` string.

So, what you're doing here:

```
wordCount = int(len(outputString))
pleaseWork =  (random.randint(0,wordCount))
print('Word number ',pleaseWork,' is ', (sentence[pleaseWork]))
```

can be shortened to:

```
pleaseWork =  random.randint(0, len(outputString))
print('Word number ',pleaseWork,' is ', (sentence[pleaseWork]))
```

Do you see it now? `pleaseWork` contains a number between `0` and the length of `outputString`. **BUT** then you're using that number to access your list `sentence`. What happens if `outputString` has 100 characters and `sentence` has only three items? Well... You're quite likely to obtain an integer bigger than `2` in that `random.randint` call. Let's say you get... `50`... What happens when you try to access the 50th item a list with three items?

```
>>> [1, 2, 3][50]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So, what you should do is change the range of that `randint` to the number of items in your `sentence` list:

```
    wordCount = int(len(sentence))
    pleaseWork = (random.randint(0, wordCount))
```

Full example:

```
def sentenceSplit():
    print ('Think of a sentence')
    print ('Type the sentence one word at a time pressing enter after each word')
    print ("When you have finished the sentence enter 'exit'")
    print ('')

sentence = []
while True:
    word = raw_input('')
    print ('Accepted', word)
    if word == 'exit':
        print ('')
        print ('Your original sentence was')
        outputString = " ".join(sentence)
        print (outputString)
        wordCount = int(len(sentence))
        pleaseWork = (random.randint(0, wordCount))
        print('Word number ', pleaseWork, ' is ', (sentence[pleaseWork]))

        break
    sentence.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the number of characters in the sentence to generate an index for the words in the sentence. Change `wordCount = int(len(outputString))` to `wordCount = len(sentence) - 1` to get an appropriate index.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get two different random numbers or words since you only called `randint` once. The problem is two things:

1. `wordCount` is currently the number of characters in the string. Use `len(sentence)` instead.
2. `randint` is inclusive of its upper bound (unlike `range` which excludes it so that you don't have to think about stuff like this) meaning that `random.randint(0,wordCount)` sometimes returns `wordCount` and so `pleaseWork == wordCount == len(sentence)` (assuming you do the above) is a possiblity, and `sentence[len(sentence)]` is bound to throw an error. Use `random.randint(0,wordCount-1)`.